# ArrayList gets clear after coming back from another activity

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

This is strange because yesterday this code was working but not today. I´m pretty sure I didn´t change anything.

The thing is that I have an empty ArrayList at first. Then I make a call to another activity which will suply to the previous activity an String which I add into the ArrayList. The content of this ArrayList is employed to fill a ListView.

The problem is that every time I start that new Activity and it returns a new String, my ArrayList is empty, so I just see the last returned String on my ListView.

I tried something about onSaveInstanceState, but it didn´t help. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
ArrayList<String> rules = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_filters);

    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFilters);     

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rules);

    myList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){   
        String aux = data.getExtras().getString(S.RULE);

        rules.add(aux); 
        // here rules.size() is always 1        
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Edit: 
I call the other activity from a simply method with this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityAddRule.class);     
startActivityForResult(i, S.REQUEST_CODE_0);
```

I return the data from  that second activity from another method like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    String rule = someOperations();
    i.putExtra(S.RULE, rule);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
```

Comment: Can you show the part of code where you call the other activity, and where you return the data from that second activity?

Comment: This code is fine but please show me the code that start second activity. I think that you finish the current activity when launch second activity that is why list onCreate() is called and list size is always 1

Comment: From what I guess, the return result is not necessarily called. Are you sure it must return a non empty string whenever the second activity starts?

Comment: I couldn´t find a solution with the code in that way, so I followed other approach more practical but less elegant.

I send the whole ArrayList<String> to the second Activity which adds a new String and returns agains the whole ArrayList.

Maybe it´s not brilliant but in this case I´m hoping not to manage sizes of ArrayList longer than 10 or 20 max.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. Make sure that `setResult(RESULT_OK, i)` is always called whenever the second activity starts.